# How to make just one dll for multiple custom rules inside CodeIt.right static code analyzer?

Tags: c#, dll, static-analysis

I am using CodeIt.Right to create custom rules. Each custom rule project creates one dll file, which has to be placed in Rules folder inside codeit.right directory. I do not want multiple dll files for multiple custom rules. I want just one dll file. Is there any way to make multiple custom rules in the same project so that in the end I will get just one dll containing all the rules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add all your related custom rules into a single project and compile that as an assembly.

I hope this helps.